# How to set the holo dark theme in a Android app?

Tags: android, android-theme

How can I set the dark holo theme in my app?
At this time I got this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light" />
```

But when I change it to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dark" />
```

I get an error `error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Dark'.`

How to solve the problem?

Comment: what resource error? elaborate...

Comment: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Dark'.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

change `parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dark"`
to `parent="android:Theme.Holo"`

The holo dark theme is called Holo

Comment: Took me a few days to find this post. When changing the theme to Holo, the preview works fine, but in styles.xml I get parent with the ".Dark" incorrectly added. And that is why it kept on showing the white theme. Added a bug report for this...

Comment: It turns out that changing the preview theme, doesn't effect any files. It is just for previewing what the theme looks like.

Answer (score 29):

By default android will set Holo to the Dark theme. There is no theme called Holo.Dark, there's only Holo.Light, that's why you are getting the resource not found error.

So just set it to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo" />
```

Answer (score 8):

According the android.com, you only need to set it in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme

Adding the theme attribute to your application element worked for me:

--AndroidManifest.xml--

...

<application ...

```
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"/>
  ...
```

</application>

Comment: While that is a workable solution .... it is a good practice to keep the theme changes in styles.xml and refer in manifest

Answer (score 1):

In your application android manifest file, under the application tag you can try several of these themes.

Replace

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

with different themes defined by the android system. They can be like:-

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

Each of these themes will have a different effect on your application like the DeviceDefault.Dialog will make your application look like a dialog box. You should try more of these. You can have a look from the android sdk or simply use auto complete in Eclipse IDE to explore the various available options.

A correct way to define your own theme would be to edit the `styles.xml` file present in the resources folder of your application.

Comment: Yes, the right way is to edit the styles.xml to set the theme. Eg: <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">