# Why my Drawer menu looks black?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have created a Drawer Menu Example, Following is my source code,

```
public class DrawerActivity extends Activity 
{
    private String [] menuOptions = new String[] { "Option1", "Option2","Option3" };
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; 


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> ( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menuOptions );
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) 
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) 
            {
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) 
            {
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };      

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) 
        {
            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
}
```

This is the code of my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.drawerdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".DrawerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The code is working fine but my Drawer menu appears as black, see the image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/toEfm.png

Can you please tell me where did I done mistake ?

Comment: Can I get reason for -1 vote ?

Comment: You have to use different theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/action_bar_header" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- The main content view -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <!-- The navigation drawer -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Change background color of your menu layout

Comment: Correct, there was `#111` set as listview's background, When I replace it with `#FFF`, Now it is showing me menu list with white background.

Comment: Already did it, but I can't vote up your answer as I dont have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the theme for your Activity.

Under your res/values folder, go to the styles.xml file and change your theme.

This can be done like so:

> [How to set the holo dark theme in a Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707560/how-to-set-the-holo-dark-theme-in-a-android-app)